# Tomcat customized servi ce instead of Catalina

Tags: tomcat7

I am working on project in which the client has included the tomcat as a part of their project i.e they created a tomcat in their project.

Now they use customized service instead of Default Catalina Service mentioned in server.xml.
Below is the code snippet.

```
<Service name="Turn" className="com.turn.product.servlet.TomcatTurnFullService">
```

Now issue is I am having the class

> com.turn.product.servlet.TomcatTurnFullService

in our project and also its class file is generated but not included in Jar file.
So the issue is when I start to run tomcat than error is classNotFoundException eventhough I have given path of the folder having class files and other necessary jars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that we can use the class files as reference, its not necessary that the class file must be in jar file.

For referencing the class file I have provided the wild card path in the classpath.

If guys you have nay queries regarding tomcat can post question or mention in comments.

Thanks and Regards,
Ankit Shah